# ROS Gazebo filesystem details?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new to ROS and want to spawn models in urdf format from ROS in Gazebo. I have come across numerous tutorials but none of them is clear as to where I am supposed to save my urdf file, as well as the mesh files that the urdf uses...Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196677/ros-gazebo-filesystem-details?/) by [Haylie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20690/haylie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The common practice is to have a `/urdf` and a `/mesh` directory in your package's root directory. However, you are free to save your urdf and mesh files where ever you want, just make sure you point to the correct location in your launch files.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2014-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haylie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20690/haylie/) on 2014-11-04**:
In the launch file, when I write the location of the file as "home/user/"... it doesn't work...I have checked the location of the files, they are correct

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-11-05**:
It would help if you add the relevant line of your launch file and the error you are getting to your question.

**Comment by [Haylie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20690/haylie/) on 2014-11-09**:
thank you, but I figured it out :) I made a catkin package and placed all the files there according to this tutorial
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_roslaunch